# MySQL PHP not storing full file to BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, centos

I have just set up a new LAMP server running CentOS 6, Apache 2.2.15, PHP 5.5.25 and MySQL 5.5.43. I installed php and mysql from webtatic and am using the mysqlnd extension.

I have transferred over code and databases from a much older LAMP set up. Most of the site works fine and has transferred well.

However the storage of files in the database has ceased to function properly. What I mean by this is that files are no longer being stored fully, the last roughly 20% is lost. I have spent quite a while trying to work out what the cause might be and am fairly confident it is happening at the "php saving to mysql" stage.

In other words, the file makes it to the server full size, however by the time it hits the DB as a LONGBLOB it has lost some of it's size. But as I have to download it out of the DB to check it's size it could be an issue with the delivery of the file.

I am using phpmyadmin for the moment and it and both my php code have exactly the same issue. No matter whether I use my uploader or that of phpmyadmin (via insert/edit choose file) the LONGBLOB filesize shown in phpmyadmin ends up being smaller than the original file.

Then when I download it either via my file delivery or through phpmyadmins, the file is delivered at the correct dimensions but the bottom 20% is gray/white/colour.

I'm totally stumped! I've tried messing with packet/memory/upload limits, collation formats and DB Engines. But I just can't get it to store/deliver the whole file.

Anyone have any ideas?

Let me know if you need more info to help.

Thanks

---

Edit 1: I've now narrowed it down to it being a problem with PHP's delivery of files to the client's browser. For whatever reason when file content comes from a database field it is not delivered complete. As I mentioned, this happens with both my code and phpmyadmin. Any ideas?

---

Edit 2: I've done a further test and can successfully write the file from the database to the server's filesystem using PHP. The file is complete! This can only mean the way PHP is sending the data from the database is the problem. But what's changed between my old and new server?

Comment: Further to the above I have just noticed that all the existing files stored in DB (as transferred from old server) are not delivering correctly either!

This would mean the issue is with how the LONGBLOB data is being pulled from MySQL and being interpreted by PHP. I do not think this is a PHP coding issue though as both phpmyadmin and my code suffer from this.

Comment: What is the declaration of the field? Did you maybe specify a maximum size?

Comment: Its a LONGBLOB. Plus I migrated code and database without changes! The only thing different is the LAMP versions

Comment: Why not save the file in a folder and save the path to the folder in the database?

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. But for anyone looking. Could I rule out saving it to a folder and also any debate about it. The application is quite large and the data stored even bigger. It would be a huge amount of effort to move all existing files from the db to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After narrowing down the symptoms to PHP's sending of the data to the browser I have now discovered this was all caused by what must be a change in the way PHP generates html from PHP files (mixed with some discrepancies in the code)

The issue itself is down to white space being sent before the image headers are. In the code I'm working with a lot of files are included before the final output is generated for sending to the browser. In several of these files there were two new lines after the closing ?> php tag. As these PHP files are included before the image output is streamed they end up being white space before the header.

I first of all did a work around by doing an ob_clean() function before sending the image. Then managed to track down where the new lines actually were and removed them. So it works now.

The funny thing is the code came from a live site AS IS. Meaning the old PHP version on that site coped with these discrepancies in the code. It appears the new one is more strict or is configured differently somehow.

If anyone knows what these changes might be, please share :)

Answer (score 2):

You would see this issue if the data you are transferring (into / out-of MySQL) is larger than the max allowable packet size. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Try increasing the max packet size in the MySQL config:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My max_allowed_packet is set at 32M and there is a code imposed limit of 8MB. Also the files I'm testing with range from 10Kb to 1Mb.

The size of the file does not seem to be a trigger with this problem. Happens to ALL files no matter what size :(